# spring security username and password flow like sparklr

Tags: android, spring-security, oauth-2.0

do you know any implementation of spring security oaurh2 "username and password flow" server,
i will use it also from android client..ıt look sprıng securıty example but ı want to use clıent from androıd applıcatıon,please let me know how to develop
thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the Spring Android project? http://www.springsource.org/spring-android

Looks like it might have what you need.  Check out Section 3 in the reference manual.

Comment: yes i know about it,it is only client side,i need server side implementation

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890661/how-can-i-create-oauth-2-username-password-flow-over-spring-security/7900406#7900406