# How to write oauth client in spring?

Tags: spring-mvc, oauth

I find the example online, they usually use `curl` or the link such like `http://localhost:8080/demo4ssh-security-oauth2/oauth/token?client_id=mobile_1&client_secret=secret_1&grant_type=password&username=wangwu&password=234567` to test the oauth.
it wil get the `access token`.
And then use `http://localhost:8080/demo4ssh-security-oauth2/json?access_token=5aa5e5f9-43eb-49e3-8149-69406884cbd9`  to get the resource
But how can I do this two actions in my spring mvc code??
I have no concept where to start?
I see the spring security oauth2 example (`sparklr` and `tonr`).
But I still can't figure out where it write this actions in `tonr`.
Please give me an simple example or explain how to do this, thank you

Answer (score 2):

It's already provided by Spring. Check out [SpringOauth2RestTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2RestTemplate.html) and [EnableOAuth2Client](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configuration/EnableOAuth2Client.html) annotations.

It's suggested that you first have some idea about the OAuth2 dance to have better understanding. Suggested [blog](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2).

[Related SOF question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864295/how-to-use-oauth2resttemplate) that illustrate how to configure and user Oauth2 protected resource.