# Spring boot, Spring OAuth2, REST

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-oauth2

I connect only to Auth server and i need the JWT, by console is all ok, but not RestTemplate, i haven't idea how to do.

What would be the equivalent of the following:

curl -u secretId:secret http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/token -d username=user-d password=password -d grant_type=password

I need to use Spring RestTemplate, any idea how to?.

thanks and regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some references: 1. [How to use OAuth2RestTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864295/how-to-use-oauth2resttemplate). 2. http://websystique.com/spring-security/secure-spring-rest-api-using-oauth2/  3.http://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-restful/spring-restful-client-resttemplate-example/

Comment: Thaks, was usefull