# ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails - Pass clientid and secret to generate oauth2 token

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I followed the accepted answer mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864295/how-to-use-oauth2resttemplate) to generate OAuth2 token. However I get HTTP 401 response. When I debugged, I saw that `clientid` and `clientsecret` are not passed as part of form in the HTTP request. I only see the below listed values being passed. Should I do anything additional in order to pass `clientid` and `clientsecret` as well?

```
{grant_type=[password], username=[username], password=[password]}
```

Comment: @dur In header I see [Authorization=[Basic Y3RwX2lkOmN0cF9zZWNyZXQ=]]

Comment: When I run it using rest client , I am passing all these as part of form body.

Comment: @dur the authorization server is managed by a third party app to which I don't have access to. The client id and secret are same as what you mentioned. Another thing I am suspecting is content-type. When running using external rest client , I provided the content-type as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". However I haven't set that explicitly in program. Do I have to do that?

Comment: It works now :) had to set resource.setClientAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.form);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your client uses HTTP basic authentication scheme by default, but your server expects "form" authentication scheme.

Your server is not OAuth 2 compliant, see [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.3.1):

> **2.3.1.  Client Password**
>
> Clients in possession of a client password MAY use the HTTP Basic
> authentication scheme as defined in [RFC2617] to authenticate with
> the authorization server.  The client identifier is encoded using the
> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" encoding algorithm per
> Appendix B, and the encoded value is used as the username; the client
> password is encoded using the same algorithm and used as the
> password.  The authorization server MUST support the HTTP Basic
> authentication scheme for authenticating clients that were issued a
> client password.

But you can change the authentication scheme of your client to "form", see [OAuth 2 Developers Guide](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html):

> `clientAuthenticationScheme:` The scheme used by your client to authenticate to the access token endpoint. Suggested values: "http_basic" and "form". Default: "http_basic". See section 2.1 of the OAuth 2 spec.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out by your explanation. In my case, initially I set the client authentication scheme as AuthenticationScheme.header and I was getting invalid_client_id. Once I changed it to AuthenticationScheme.query, it worked good.