# disable http authentication when call /oauth/token in spring oauth

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I write oAuth Server with spring framework 
configure client like this

```
@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clientDetailsServiceConfigurer) throws Exception {
    clientDetailsServiceConfigurer.inMemory()
            .withClient("aaaa")
            .secret("bbbb")
            .scopes("email")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
            .authorities("test");

}
```

but when i call /oauth/token method this method ask for http basic authentication i want disabled http authentication

Comment: Do you want to change to form login or do you want to disable client authentication at all?

Comment: i want disable http basic authenticate and accept client_id and client_secret from query string

Comment: Sorry, wrong one, the right one should be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35785628/spring-security-oauth-2-0-client-secret-always-required-for-authorization-code.

Comment: If it works, please flag your question as a dupe and reload your question, to accept the dupe in the box at the top of your question. It helps other users, to find the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails - Pass clientid and secret to generate oauth2 token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43859342/resourceownerpasswordresourcedetails-pass-clientid-and-secret-to-generate-oaut)