# How to extract authentication token in @Controller

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security, oauth, single-sign-on

I have Spring Boot app that uses OAuth 2.0 and Authorization Server. When I try to access a secured page, I get a redirect to the login page of my authorization server (Blitz Identity Provider) and everything works like it should.

My problem is that *I can't extract authorization token in `@Controller` (on the secured page)*. That token I want to use later to authorize in second application.

- Tried [this thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864295/how-to-use-oauth2resttemplate) (in answer) and it worked, I got my token back,
  but as you can see, it's a hardcode of username and password
  parameters and it's like login over login -- I don't need to login
  for a second time (on authenticated page).
- Tried to output *authentication.getDetails()*, it shows token type
  and token like *< TOKEN >*, but it's not enough.
- Tried to lookup token in request-response headers, but didn't find
  it, so authorization server doesn't send it in headers.

Here are 2 files which can help you to understand some part of my context.

*application.yml*

```
server:
  port: 8080
  context-path: /
  session:
    cookie:
      name:FIRSTSESSION
security:
  basic:
    enabled: false
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: test_id
      clientSecret: f3M5m9a2Dn0v15l
      accessTokenUri: http://server:9000/blitz/oauth/te
      userAuthorizationUri: http://server:9000/blitz/oauth/ae?scope=test_scope
    resource:
      userInfoUri: http://server:9000/blitz/oauth/me
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: DEBUG
```

*SsoController.java*

```
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@Controller
public class SsoController {

    @RequestMapping("/secondService")
    public String getContent(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        model.addAttribute("submittedValue", authentication.getDetails());
        return "secondService";
    } 
}
```

So, what you can suggest? How can I extract authorization token in this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have configured oauth2 authorization/resource server you can try below code:

```
@Autowired
private TokenStore tokenStore;

@RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET },
                value = "/oauth/me")
public Map<String, Object> userInfo (OAuth2Authentication auth)
{
    final OAuth2AuthenticationDetails details = 
        (OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) auth.getDetails();

    //token
    String accessToken = details.getTokenValue();

    //reference
    final OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = 
        tokenStore.readAccessToken(details.getTokenValue());

   // clientid
    String clientId = auth.getOAuth2Request().getClientId();
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I needed! I got my token by implementing this code: OAuth2AuthenticationDetails = auth = (OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails(); accessToken = auth.getTokenValue();