# How to do OAuth 2 API call and get the response

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I want to create a Spring boot application, that will call an API through OAuth2 process.

I've already checked [this](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_social_login_simple) but can some explain it to me in a simple way.

All I have is the URL (that gets the Bearer token), Client ID and Client Secret.

Once the bearer token is retrieved I want to get the call the actual API with the retrieved bearer token put in the header, So I get the response.

Comment: Your question is missing specifics of API you want to call. Which grant type is your API using? If the bearer token you received is an access token then that is sufficient to make an API call.

Comment: This tutorial might be useful http://sivatechlab.com/create-rest-client-spring/

Answer (score 1):

In Spring,
you can use the `RestTemplate.exchange` method to make API calls.

Since the API is secured using an OAuth2.0 - Access token (bearer token),
the token must be passed in the "Authorization" header.

Try the code shown below to make an API call with header request:

```
String url = "https://you-api-url";
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

// set the headers 
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token_value); 

HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(headers);

// send the GET request
HttpEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

// display the response
System.out.println("Response" + response.getBody());
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: -1 This is just wrong. You should never send your "client_secret" as a header to the target API. The idea of OAuth is that you use your clientId/secret to request a bearer token. Then you use that bearer token to make the call to the secure API. You need to use OAuth2RestTemplate for that. See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth2-authentication-with-reddit or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864295/how-to-use-oauth2resttemplate

Answer (score 0):

For getting a resource protected by OAuth2.0, first you need to get a valid access token(assuming the flow is authorization_code based.). It will usually be a POST method call to the token endpoint with credentials Base64 encoded. For this API call, you can use RestTemplate. If the request is valid , you  will get a response and will have to extract access token from the response, and add it as the Authorization header mentioned in the answer by
@Mohit_Kalra
So in effect, this will be 2 API call to get the response.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).