# clear Cookies with RestTemplate before make HTTP-call

Tags: java, cookies, session-cookies, resttemplate

I use Spring-Boot 2.0.2 `RestTemplate` to make following scenario:

I'm a Rest-Consumer (client), which :

1. first need to log in on a Spring-Security-Check
2. then make a second call to get the data.

First, I was thinking to make the auth call and manually read the JSESSIONID Cookie from SET-COOKIE and set it on the second call in the header. Here my first try:

The RestClient :

```
@Service
public class RestClient {
    private static final String ENDPOINT_DATA = "/data";
    private static final String ENDPOINT_SECURITY_CHECK = "/j_spring_security_check";

    private static final String HTTP_HEADER_KEY_SET_COOKIE = "Set-Cookie";
    private static final String HTTP_HEADER_KEY_COOKIE = "Cookie";

    private static final String PROPERTY_SPRING_SECURITY_USER = "j_username";
    private static final String PROPERTY_SPRING_SECURITY_PASS = "j_password";

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private final RestConfig restConfig;

    @Autowired
    public RestClient(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder, final RestConfig restConfig) {

        notNull(restTemplateBuilder, "restTemplateBuilder must not be null!");
        this.restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder
                .additionalCustomizers(new NoRedirectionHandlingRestTemplateCostumizer())
                .build();

        notNull(restConfig, "openIdConfig must not be null!");
        this.restConfig = restConfig;
    }

    public String getData() {
        final String jSessionCockie = jSpringSecurityLogin();
        return getAuthorizeCode(jSessionCockie);
    }

    private String jSpringSecurityLogin() {
        // read config
        final String fullLoginUri = restConfig.getUrl() + ENDPOINT_SECURITY_CHECK;
        final String user = restConfig.getUser();
        final String password = restConfig.getPassword();

        // Build entity that is send
        final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        final String body = PROPERTY_SPRING_SECURITY_USER + "=" + user + "&" + PROPERTY_SPRING_SECURITY_PASS + "=" + password;
        final HttpEntity<String> toSend = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);

        final String jSessionIdCockie;

        final ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(fullLoginUri, toSend, String.class);

        // Get String "JSESSIONID=XXXX". If there are other Cookies, propably will fail.
        if (HttpStatus.FOUND.equals(response.getStatusCode()) && response.getHeaders().containsKey(HTTP_HEADER_KEY_SET_COOKIE)) {
            jSessionIdCockie = response.getHeaders().get(HTTP_HEADER_KEY_SET_COOKIE).get(0);
        } else {
            throw new Error();
        }

        return jSessionIdCockie;
    }

    private String getAuthorizeCode(final String jSessionCockie) {
        // read config
        final String fullDataUri = restConfig.getUrl() + ENDPOINT_DATA;

        // Build entity that is send
        final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add(HTTP_HEADER_KEY_COOKIE, jSessionCockie);
        final HttpEntity<Void> toSend = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

        final ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(fullDataUri, HttpMethod.GET, toSend, String.class);

        if (HttpStatus.OK.equals(response.getStatusCode()) && response.hasBody()) {
            return response.getBody();
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

To be complete, here the Costumizer used in the Constructor:

```
class NoRedirectionHandlingRestTemplateCostumizer implements RestTemplateCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void customize(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                .disableRedirectHandling()
                .build();
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient));
    }
}
```

Now, when I make some Function-Tests with Wiremock I see folowing in the wiremock-reqeust History for the Data-call:

```
{
  ...
  "headers":
  {
    "Cookie": [
      "JSESSIONID=axcvueiornxniuwherwuieoiun,asdpfoiu",
      "JSESSIONID=axcvueiornxniuwherwuieoiun,asdpfoiu"
    ],
    ...
  },
  "cookies":
  {
    "JSESSIONID": [
      "axcvueiornxniuwherwuieoiun,asdpfoiu",
      "axcvueiornxniuwherwuieoiun,asdpfoiu"
    ]
  }
  ...
}
```

Wait - JSESSIONID is set 2 times. Cool REST handles it for me !

Second try: I can remove the Cookie handing. And it works.

But first and second try have on problem: After the first call of `RestClient.getData()` all following calls to the login-Endpoint also have the JSESSIONID set. I don't know how the Rest-Producer can handle this (Session-timeout e.c.t.).

### Now my problem/question:

I would like to force `RestTemplate` to forget/clear all Cookies before making the login-call (reason description before). Is there an possibility ? I did not found anything that worked.

---

My Workaround right now is to disable the Cookie management of `RestTemplate` and do all manually like in first try. The disabling of the CookieManagment can be done over the `RestTemplateCustomizer`:

```
class NoRedirectionHandlingRestTemplateCostumizer implements RestTemplateCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void customize(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                .disableRedirectHandling()
                .disableCookieManagement()
                .build();
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient));
    }
}
```

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this ?I am facing the same issue and even adding the workaround is not working.

Comment: Hi  user964819 . I did not find an other solution then the workaround I wrote.
If you want to use standard OAuth 2, then there is a Implementation in Spring : see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864295/how-to-use-oauth2resttemplate
In me case, it wasn't standard, that is why the hack of reconfiguration of the HttpClient

Answer (score 2):

As it is mentioned in the question, first we need to disable cookie management in the following way

CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
.setConnectionManager(cm)
.setRetryHandler(retryHandler)
.setKeepAliveStrategy(connectionKeepAliveStrategy)
.disableCookieManagement()
.evictExpiredConnections().evictIdleConnections(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
.build();

And set "Cookie" header like any other header.

public ResponseEntity getContent(String url, Map<String, String> headers, Map<String, String> cookies){
HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

```
    // add headers
    for(String key : headers.keySet()){
        requestHeaders.set(key, headers.get(key));
    }

    // add cookies
    List<String> allCookieValues = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String key : cookies.keySet()){
        String value = cookies.get(key);
        String cookieString = MessageFormat.format("{0}={1}", key,value);
        allCookieValues.add(cookieString);
    }
    requestHeaders.addAll(HttpHeaders.COOKIE, allCookieValues);

    HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(requestHeaders);
    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(url);
    URI uri = builder.build(true).toUri();
    ResponseEntity responseEntity = null;
    try {
        responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, byte[].class);
```

......
......

From the response, if you want to read we can read the cookies in the following way

List responseCookies = responseEntity.getHeaders().get(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE);
Map<String, String> cookieNameValue = new HashMap<>();

```
    if(requestCookies != null){
        cookieNameValue.putAll(requestCookies);
    }

    for(String cookie : responseCookies){
        String[] cookieParts = cookie.split(";")[0].split("=");
        cookieNameValue.put(cookieParts[0], cookieParts[1]);
    }
    return cookieNameValue;
```