# Spring Boot Sending Http Request for Oauth

Tags: spring-boot, rest, http, http-headers, httprequest

I wanna get zoom api access token for my Spring Boot application. I wanna add my base url several parameters than an header. I couldn't find any library for that. how can i build exact same http below?(It a c# code)

```
            RestClient restClient = new RestClient();
            RestRequest request = new RestRequest();

            request.AddQueryParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code");
            request.AddQueryParameter("code", code);
            request.AddQueryParameter("redirect_uri", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUrl"]);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", string.Format(AuthorizationHeader));

            restClient.BaseUrl = new Uri("https://zoom.us/oauth/token");
            var response = restClient.Post(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of OAuthRestTemplate or WebClient provided by the Spring Framework.
Reference links:
[How to use OAuth2RestTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864295/how-to-use-oauth2resttemplate)

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webclient-oauth2